# UIBarButton Item Won't Appear in Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview, uibarbuttonitem

I understand there are other questions like this but so far I have not been able to get an answer that works for so this is why I am writing this.

I right now have the following code to place a leftBarButtonItem:

```
   let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        setupNavBar()
    }

    func setupNavBar() {

        //left bar button item setup

        let url = URL(string: (self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString)!)
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
        imageView?.image = UIImage(data: data!)

        imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 1.5
        imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        imageView?.layer.cornerRadius=(imageView?.bounds.width)! / 2

        let profileImageButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: (self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString)!), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(UserGroupsMainViewController.navLeftBarButtonTapped))

        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = profileImageButton
    }

    func navLeftBarButtonTapped() {

    }
```

For some reason, the button does not appear on the navigation controller. I do know for sure that I have a URL that is not nil because I tested it in my print output. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does `UIImage(named: (self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString)!)` return an image and is `self.navigationController?` nil? Is `self.user` nil?

Comment: are you allocating the frame of imageview

Comment: Is this view controller actually embedded in a navigation controller? And why do you use `self.navigationController?.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...` instead of `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...`?

Comment: And your code is full of bombs (`!`) waiting to go off. Please learn how to safely unwrap optionals.

Comment: And using `self.user?.photoURL?.absoluteString` with `UIImage(named:)` is completely wrong for several reasons.

Comment: self. user is not nil and also @rmaddy what do you suggest I do about fixing my problem

Answer (score 1):

Just use `navigationItem` not `navigationController.navigationItem`

Ok, I just saw your problem.

You are using a URL as the "name" of an image. It doesn't work that way.

The function `UIImage(named: "blah")` will load an image from the app bundle stored with the name given.

If you want to download the image from a URL then you need to have a download task run in the background and then load the image once that's done.

Try using the AlamofireImage framework also.

Comment: @RohanVasishth oh wait... what are you expecting to happen with the image? Is it one you are trying to download?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to download an image from the URL.